# Javascript to detect domain of previous page

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a site logo that I want to animate (fade in) when a user first arrives into my domain. But, I do not want to animate this if the user arrives from another page in my domain.

I have the animation routine sorted (jquery) but I don't know how to detect when a user is landing on my site from elsewhere (link, or through typing in the URL).

I guess there might be an elegant javascript solution for this? Could anyone let me know what it might be...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Javascript has function `document.referrer.split('/');` using this you should be able to find if they came from a page on your domain or not.

Hope this helps.

Example:

```
if(document.referrer.split('/')[2]!=location.hostname){
    //User came from other domain or from direct
}else{
    //User came from another page on your site
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am developing/testing this website based on my local hard drive, should I expect document.referrer and location.hostname to return anything in this case (at the moment they are just returning empty strings)?

Comment: If you directly enter the url into the address bar the referrer will return nothing (this is normal). If the url is file://c..... then the hostname will not return anything. But it will return the hostname once hosted.

Comment: Hi, yes it worked fine once I accessed it through our test web server. Thanks again!

Comment: I dont think this works anymore. If the user loaded your page directly from the new tab page (no referrer) it has itself as the referrer.